# How to get all the documents to use in react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get all the documents from a collection to display in a react component, I would like to put all the docs in an array
I've tried doing this :

```js
export const getProjects = async () => {
  firestore
    .collection("projects")
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      return querySnapshot.docs;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
};
```

but I get undefined, if I do a console.log(querySnapshot.docs) it works.

Comment: Have you considered setting to state on `.then()` callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Problem

You're not returning `firestore.collection(...)` from the `getProjects` function, you're only returning it from inside `then` callback function.

#### Solution

Return `firestore.collection(...)` from the `getProjects` like this

```js
export const getProjects = async () => {
  return firestore
    .collection("projects")
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      return querySnapshot.docs;
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
};
```